# Возможно ли както увеличить надежность nodejs сервера при закрытии сессии?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vps

Достаточно часто на VPS серверная nodejs программа выдает "session closed", после чего естественно ничего работать уже не будет либо будет работать некоректно. При этом ошибок никаких нет. Теоритически поддержание соединения можно достичь, используя forever или другими способами.(Их несколько...) Но как быть с данными, которые пришли на сервер и в моменте их обработки сервер упал? Теоритически после поднятия сервера, даже если это произошло мгновенно, поступившие данные на сервере до разрыва будут утеряны. И тут уже совсем не важно как быстро сервер был поднят - данные утеряны и это факт и как следствие дальнейшая работа программы будет уже некорректной(ну конкретно в моем случае). Каким способом добиться отсутствия возможности аварийного завершения nodejs серверной программы? Прошу не сравнивать поведение nodejs на локалке и VPS так как оно разное. На локалке все работает без нареканий, а вот на VPS с регулярной частотой он падает..

Comment: Не жмотитесь и купите VPS за нормальные деньги с нормальными ресурсами, которых будет хватать ноде, и тогда не будет падать (или по крайней мере редко)

Comment: Вообще, прежде чем что-либо делать с падениями, нужно сперва выяснить, почему вообще падает. Ничего не бывает просто так

Comment: Нет никакого способа кроме пересмотра логики самой программы. Серверу node падать даже не надо. Это интернет, любое соединение в любой момент может быть разорвано, программа должна быть к этому готова, восстановить его и начать с места обрыва. А если все таки падает сам сервер - это уже надо разбираться с сервером, нормально написанный код может работать годами (при условии, что железо не ломается)

Comment: @andreymal, VPS хороший. Ресурсов хватает. У меня еще около 700 мб оперативы всегда там свободно. Как узнать от чего может падать? Можете подсказать, может быть где то можно посмотреть логи? В консоле ничего не выдает. При чем он может работать долго без сбоев, а может сразуже. Чаще всего если запустить серверную программу сразу после перезагрузки сервера VPS

Comment: @Mike, Логика там самая банальная... Там всего около 1500 строк. Все уже 100 раз пересмотренно, но были бы ошибки, но их нет... Возможно есть отдельный файл в который нода записывает логи и причину? Можете подсказать. Просто синтаксически там ничего нет провакационного.

Comment: Логируйте интервалом память, посмотрите что с ней происходит перед падением, возможно на локалке вы просто не дождались крайней точки.